# python dash diagram of digital signal

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I track a digital signal of a slide door (open/closed). Whenever the signal changes I append the time and the new state (0/1) into a csv file.

I would like to add this data to a python dash diagram that already shows a scatter chart of the room temperature.

When I set the diagram type for the door state to scatter it shows the state but I get a ramp from the last state to the new one and I would like to show the signal as a rectangular line.

Will I need to extend my data with intermediate states to get around the ramps or is there a diagram type that would be better suited for this kind of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a scatterplot. It's written in the documentation.

https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

(Interpolation with Line Plots)

You can configure how the line should look with the attribute line_shape in the form:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="hv",
                    line_shape='hv'))
```

There are 6 different shapes to choose from. What you need is the option "hv".

Hope this answer helps.